# JetBrains PyCharm: Length of PATH is bigger than 8192 bytes

Tags: windows, installation, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I would appreciate if you could let me know how to prevent the following error while installing `JetBrains PyCharm`.

```
Length of PATH is bigger than 8192 bytes.$\r$\nInstaller can not update it
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not select **Update PATH variable** while installation or remove some needless items from `PATH` if any. `PATH` on Windows has a limited length.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks I upvote your answer. Could you please let me know how to remove needless items from PATH?

Comment: I added the images to the answer. It's Windows 10, just type "environment variables" in the search field, open the corresponding window, double click on `PATH` and remove rows which are no longer relevant.